# Why does my NSMutableArray contain nil on some indices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, mapbox

## Problem:

After I fill an `NSMutableArray` with objects and try to do something with it, it contains `(id)0x0` on some indices. I thought adding nil to an `NSMutableArray` wasn't possible at all in Objective-C so I am wondering why this happens.

### When does this happen?

'Sometimes' unfortunately. It is reproducible by downloading more than ~5000 tiles, just to get the amount high enough for a chance for this to occur. Even with more than 5000 tiles it sometimes goes flawlessly.

### Context:

My app has a button which starts a download for map tiles for a specific region. The download happens parallel in background threads and reports back for every tile downloaded.

To allow for canceling the download, in my downloader singleton I have a temporary `NSMutableArray` which saves a hash from every tile downloaded. After canceling, I can use that list of hashes to delete every saved tile in the database.

Saving the hashes during downloading seems to go fine, but when I actually want to do anything with it (I use `[_currentTileHashes copy]` to change it to an `NSArray` to give to the delete method), it throws an `NSInvalidArgumentException`on that line saying:

```
-[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[3402]
```

When I use the debugger to inspect the `_currentTileHashes` mutable array, I indeed see that one or two of the indices is actually nil or `(id)0x0`. This screenshot illustrates it:

[image: Debugger shows nil in array]

### Relevant code:

This code is from the callback for every tile download where it hashes the tile, adds it to the hashes array and calls back to the UI for progress:

```
- (void)tileCache:(RMTileCache *)tileCache didBackgroundCacheTile:(RMTile)tile withIndex:(NSUInteger)tileIndex ofTotalTileCount:(NSUInteger)totalTileCount {
    DebugLog(@"Cached tile %lu of %lu.", (unsigned long)tileIndex, (unsigned long)totalTileCount);
    if (_currentlyDownloading) {
        float progress = (float)tileIndex / (float)totalTileCount;

        NSDictionary *progressDict = @{@"progress" : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:progress],
                                       @"routeId" : _downloadingRoute.routeId};

        [_currentTileHashes addObject:[RMTileCache tileHash:tile]];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         postNotificationName:@"routeTileDownloaded"
         object:progressDict];
    }
}
```

This is the way the tile gets hashed (this is from the [Mapbox iOS SDK](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk)):

```
+ (NSNumber *)tileHash:(RMTile)tile
{
    return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:RMTileKey(tile)];
}

uint64_t RMTileKey(RMTile tile)
{
    uint64_t zoom = (uint64_t)tile.zoom & 0xFFLL; // 8bits, 256 levels
    uint64_t x = (uint64_t)tile.x & 0xFFFFFFFLL;  // 28 bits
    uint64_t y = (uint64_t)tile.y & 0xFFFFFFFLL;  // 28 bits

    uint64_t key = (zoom << 56) | (x << 28) | (y << 0);

    return key;
}
```

And finally, the code where the exception occurs:

```
- (void)tileCacheDidCancelBackgroundCache:(RMTileCache *)tileCache {
    DebugLog(@"Finished canceling tile download");

    [tileCache removeAllCachedImagesForTileHashes:[_currentTileHashes copy]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"routeTileDownloadCanceled"
     object:nil];
}
```

*Tested on iOS 8.4, 8.4.1 (iPhone 6) and 7.1 (iPhone 4)*

Feel free to ask for more clarification if something is unclear.

Comment: Well AFAIK you can `[NSNull null]` in an array.

Comment: Yeah that is true, but that would be visible in the debugger and would be explicitly set by me. This is about having real nil in the `NSMutableArray` without me explicitly putting it there.

Comment: `NSMutableArray` is not thread safe - if you are downloading multiple tiles concurrently you *will* have issues unless you guard updates to the array through @synchromized or some other technique.

Comment: I would recommend to avoid crash you should put `if(tile!=nil)[arr addObject:tile];`

Comment: @Paulw11 Very good point! I did not know this. I'll look into this and try one of the solutions.

Comment: @iphonic I tried this already, unfortunately the tile is never nil when it enters that method so it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @iphonic - If the object is being deleted on the fly the nil check is unsafe at best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSMutableArray` is not thread safe, so updating an instance from multiple, concurrent, background downloads is likely to lead to corruption in your array - as you are seeing.

I would suggest using @synchronized to guard the array when you update it -

```
- (void)tileCache:(RMTileCache *)tileCache didBackgroundCacheTile:(RMTile)tile withIndex:(NSUInteger)tileIndex ofTotalTileCount:(NSUInteger)totalTileCount {
    DebugLog(@"Cached tile %lu of %lu.", (unsigned long)tileIndex, (unsigned long)totalTileCount);
    if (_currentlyDownloading) {
        float progress = (float)tileIndex / (float)totalTileCount;

        NSDictionary *progressDict = @{@"progress" : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:progress],
                                       @"routeId" : _downloadingRoute.routeId};
        @synchronized(_currentTileHashes) {
            [_currentTileHashes addObject:[RMTileCache tileHash:tile]];
        }
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         postNotificationName:@"routeTileDownloaded"
         object:progressDict];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the corruption I've been seeing! I was unaware that `NSMutableArray` wasn't thread safe, good to know.